# In Swift, how to import a target with dash in its name?

Tags: ios, macos, swift

This might be something very basic yet I just can't find the answer...

Say I have two targets in my Xcode project: foo-bar and foo-barTests

now if I want to make an identifier from foo-bar visible in foo-barTests, how do I import it?

Answer (score 42):

Okay it *was* very [basic](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/MixandMatch.html):

> **Naming Your Product Module**
>
> The name of the Xcode-generated header for Swift code, and the name of the Objective-C bridging header that Xcode creates for you, are generated from your product module name. By default, your product module name is the same as your product name. **However, if your product name has any non-alphanumeric characters, such as a period (.), they are replaced with an underscore (_) in your product module name. If the name begins with a number, the first number is replaced with an underscore.**
>
> You can also provide a custom name for the product module name, and Xcode will use this when naming the bridging and generated headers. To do this, change the Product Module Name build setting.

so `import foo-bar` becomes `import foo_bar` .

Comment: can you link to where you get this from?

Comment: @onmyway133 https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/MixandMatch.html

Comment: 'You can also provide a custom name for the product module name, and Xcode will use this when naming the bridging and generated headers. To do this, change the Product Module Name build setting.' - It isn't work. Problem described in the question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57304255/how-to-create-project-with-different-product-module-name-and-product-name-an