# How to create project with different 'Product Module Name' and 'Product Name' and import module of it into another project?

Tags: swift, xcode, build, module

I tried to implement the task described in the question but fails. Steps to reproduce:

1. Create new workspace 'WS'
   [image]
   [image]
2. Create new Cocoa Touch Framework
   [image]
   [image]

   - set 'Product Name:' = 'Product' in 'Choose options for your new project:' window. Keep other inputs auto-generated.
     [image]
   - in next wizard window set 'Add to:' = WS.
     [image]
3. Go to: 'Product (just created) -> Build Settings (all tab) -> Packaging' and set 'Product Name' = 'Product' and 'Product Module Name' = 'Module'
   [image]
   [image]
4. Build
5. Create Client project: Do step 2 but instead of Product use Client
6. Add 'Product.framework' into 'Linked Frameworks and Libraries' of Client
   [image]
7. Create 'TryToImport.swift' file in Client project, and add 'import Module' code line after auto-generated 'import Foundation' line.
   [image]
8. 'Clean Build Folder' and Build Client

The result is an error: No such module 'Module'.

I tried many things to do it but nothing helps.
As for me, the described scenario is correct.
What is wrong?
How I can do it?

My Xcode version = 10.3 (10G8)

Comment: Hello, did you ever find a solution to this?

Comment: @TeoM No. I would have answered if I had found it.

Comment: Ok too bad, we ended up forced to keep the product name same as the product module name.

Comment: I found if you remove the arm64 from build settings' valid architectures is able to compile. But not sure yet whats the relation

Answer (score 0):

I tried reproducing this behavior on `Xcode 11.2.1` and it works fine. 
I think this could be resolved for you too once you add at least 1 Swift file in the `Product` Target. Here is my Github repo that shows the problem resolved. https://github.com/tapthaker/TestProductNameChange/

Comment: fyi, your project doesn't implement the issue involved in the issue. Yes you have two different target and the second target create a framework of a different name. But the somethingElse framework have the same `product_name` and `product_module_name`